# Where and how do I use the data segment code?

Tags: javascript, json, sigma.js

I am trying to implement a graph using [sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/) but I am not sure how to do it. Where do I put the `Data` segment? Is it a javascript code?

*HTML*

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  #container {
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="sigma.min.js"></script>
<script src="sigma.parsers.json.min.js"></script>
<script>
  sigma.parsers.json('data.json', {
    container: 'container',
    settings: {
      defaultNodeColor: '#ec5148'
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Data:*

```
    {
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "n0",
      "label": "A node",
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "size": 3
    },
    {
      "id": "n1",
      "label": "Another node",
      "x": 3,
      "y": 1,
      "size": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "n2",
      "label": "And a last one",
      "x": 1,
      "y": 3,
      "size": 1
    }
  ],
  "edges": [
    {
      "id": "e0",
      "source": "n0",
      "target": "n1"
    },
    {
      "id": "e1",
      "source": "n1",
      "target": "n2"
    },
    {
      "id": "e2",
      "source": "n2",
      "target": "n0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an URL. In this case, `data.json` is a file in the same directory as your HTML file. If you wish to use JSON in code rather than from a separate file, you can do:

```
new sigma({
  container: 'container',
  graph: graph
});
```

where `graph` is the JavaScript object.

EDIT: dynamically adding a graph:

```
var s = new sigma('container');
s.graph.read(graph);
```

(You might also need `s.graph.clear()` and `s.refresh()`)

Comment: I want to dynamically add a graph when someone clicks on a container. How could I do this?